# What is Empty Function in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

in numpy empty function can give us a chunk of memory values in python . And if not then what is difference between zeros and an empty function !

Comment: `zeros` makes sure those values are all 0.  You don't need to use `empty`, especially if you don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html):

> `numpy.empty` [returns] a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries.
>
> `empty`, unlike `zeros`, does not set the array values to zero, and may therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used with caution.